# ios trying to get text to clip out of bounds of a uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, clipping

I'm trying to build a uiview that serves as a file picker. The picker can toggle open and closed by clicking on the handle bar you see in the image below. I built a custom picker view for this. I set clipsToBounds to NO on the view which allows me to place the handle slightly outside the bounds of the view. This way it sticks out like a handle on the left side of the screen when the user closes the picker. The picker slides in and out on click of the handle. The image shows the picker open.

[image: Picker view]

You'll notice the name of the files in black overlaid on top of the file images, offsetted slightly to the left. I want these names to float to outside the picker, almost as if they're overlaid partly on the white background and my picker view.

I place this text as a subview of the cell. The cell contains the file image, along with the black text. The cells are part of a uitableview, which is a subview of my custom picker view. The view hierarchy:

PickerView -> UITableView (scroller) -> UITableViewCell -> UILabel (NSMutableString)

I have set clipsToBounds = NO on the PickerView. I have tried setting clipsToBounds on the uitableview, the cell, and even the text label (UILabel), but with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you are fighting the framework. There are many more views in the table/cell hierarchy than you think there are. If any of them clips to bounds, that's it, you're stuck.

Instead of trying to make the text appear outside of your view, and fighting with the bounds and clipping, start with a PickerView which is wider and mostly clear. That way, its bounds will be bigger, extending much further to left.

In fact, in iOS 7 there is no reason why it shouldn't be a UIViewController's view and cover the whole screen with this mostly clear view (using the new custom transition animation API).

Comment: matt, thanks for your response. Say I extended my parent PickerView to the left. Do you suggest I add my text label as a subview of cell or something higher up? I added it as a subview of a cell so if someone scrolled the tableiview, the text label would keep its alignment and scroll with it.

Comment: Yes, I have not tried this but I'm suggesting that the cells and the table view should have clear backgrounds and extend further to the left (maybe even covering the whole screen if you use a presented view with a custom transition animation in iOS 7). Let me know if that doesn't work for some reason...